# Jquery query string keeping variables

Tags: php, jquery, query-string

I am attempting to keep a query string and repass it to another url.

It is originally sent to a login page to automatically log on. If the user does not exist then it will not log in and reload the page. I want it to then send the query string to the signup page and automatically sign up for the site.

when the page is reloaded I lose the query string.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">var QueryString = function () {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
    }
  } 
    return query_string;
} ();
jQuery(function() {jQuery('#email').val(QueryString.u);
jQuery('#password').val(QueryString.p);
jQuery('#submit').click();});
</script>
```

That is the code for the login page and I only need QueryString.U and QueryString.p
Is there a way to keep this.

Comment: Why are you doing this in javascript?  This seems a very fragile and insecure approach, as you should not be passing around passwords in query strings anyway.  If a user tries to login and they don't have an account, you should likely use a server-side script to redirect them to an appropriate sign-up page.

Comment: Its a single sign on from my main site to this php social engine site. It would redirect them but i need the query string from the login page. Im going to encrypt it as soon as i figure everything out

Comment: thatssss what session and cookies are for.....

Comment: @coreytoolis There are a number of better approaches to this.  If these two sites are on the same root domain, then you can use sessions/cookies.  If not, then you could use something like OAuth or some other token-based access approach.  I can assure you that relying on javascript and passing around passwords in query strings is not going to be a good path to go down.